# Return message on window.onbeforeunload custom message didn't set. it shows always default message

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had tried to return my custom message to onbeforeunload confirm box, but default message didn't change what I sent.

```js
    window.onbeforeunload  = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return 'You are leaving this page. Please confirm or data will be lost';
};
```

This Changes worked on Firefox 46.0.1
[image][image]

Comment: which browser/version? For old IEs, you need `window.event.returnValue = 'valueYouTypicallyReturn'`

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @JuanMendes, I am using Chrome 51.0.2704

Comment: @RajamohanAnguchamy Dan O has explained that the behavior has been removed from Chrome and Firefox, what are you still wondering about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to [MDN's browser compatibility chart for this event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility), custom text support has been removed from newer versions of Chrome and Firefox.  If you're using FF >= 44.0 or Chrome >= 51.0 , you'll get the default window-closing text instead of your own.

Comment: I just tried this with Firefox 47.0 on Ubuntu and I received the default text instead of yours.  (I do not have older versions of Firefox to test)

Comment: ah, so it's platform-specific?  interesting, I would not expect that.